# Animate in each card of an masonry blog archive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, css-animations

I have a masonry blog archive here: http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/news-blog/

It's in Wordpress and used a page builder plugin to build it called Elementor.

I've been trying to find ways to fade in each 'card' one by one. he posts seem to be structured like so:

```
<div class="elementor-posts-container">
 <article class="elementor-post"></article>
 <article class="elementor-post"></article>
 <article class="elementor-post"></article>
 <article class="elementor-post"></article>
</div>
```

So I enqueued a .js file into my Wordpress install, and inside the file called additional.js I added the following code:

```
$(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
});
```

I also tried this:

```
function fadeLI(elem, idx) {
    elem.eq(idx).fadeIn(500, function() {
        fadeLI(elem, (idx + 1) % elem.length);
    });
}

fadeLI($(".elementor-post"), 0);
```

I believe I have to replace the `$` in the first example with `jQuery`, so I tried that also.

I added the following CSS for the div:

```
.elementor-post { 
  display: none; 
}
```

The only thing all of this seems to do is `display:none;` the `elementor-post` divs

Being Wordpress, I did assume jQuery is there an active, I've seen it in the resources list in my browser... so I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress jQuery uses the [no conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). This means, that you need to use always `jQuery` instead of `$`.

If I try this with your first example, it works:

```
jQuery(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
});
```

But in my tests, I needed to disable all posts with the css selector `.elementor-posts .elementor-post`.

You should in this example call your function only, when the elements are fully loaded. You can achieve this by enqueueing the additional.js script [in the footer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) of the page:

```
wp_enqueue_script('additional-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/additional.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
```

Or you can wrap the function inside a `jQuery(document).ready()` function. This has the benefit, that you can pass jQuery as an `$` to everything inside this function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // you can use $ here

    $(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I ask what tests you did and how you did them? As I can't seem to get it working. I've now enqueued the additional.js file in the footer as suggested, it's still coming through it seems so that's good - I've tried both options of the js code but nothing seems to happen, I've also tried display:none; for .elementor-posts and .elementor-post just on their own nothing happens, adding the !important part, they just disappear completely... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again! :)

Comment: I just tried a little bit inside the Chrome Developer Console on your website.

If I take a look at your website, all posts are visible on page load. If I understand you correctly, you want to hide all posts on page load and then fade them in.

So first hide all posts again: `.elementor-posts .elementor-post { display: none; }`

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now: the rule gets overriden by the masonry styling. Adding `!important` won't work, because this would also override the fade in effect. You need to make your selector more specific. You could add a custom class in Elementor to the post widget, e.g. 'fade-in-posts-container'. Then use `.fade-in-post-container .elementor-posts .elementor-post { display: none; }`

Comment: Ah ok, that's working perfectly now - thanks so much for the help and also the explanation, I completely understand the issues I was facing now :)